# Failed to instantiate sessionFactory From org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We are using spring and hibernate in our application i create LocalSessionFactoryBean object then @autowire SessionFactory in Repository As Follow : Create LocalSessionFactoryBean in AppConfig

```
 @EnableCaching
 @EnableAsync
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 @Configuration
 class AppCOnfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
 @Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.xx.yyy");
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    sessionFactory.setPhysicalNamingStrategy(new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy());
    sessionFactory.setImplicitNamingStrategy(new ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl());
    return sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

In Repository We are Using @autowire annotation as

```
@Slf4j
@Repository
public class UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

}
```

We are using hibernate and spring version as below  :
  4.3.4.RELEASE
  5.2.10.Final
But when i start application i got this error :

```
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in XXX.AppConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.EnumConstantNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
```

I knew there is some issue when spring tried to got session factory from localeSessionFactoryBean But can not figure out how can we solve it.If anyone have some idea about it please help me out.

Comment: `Class AppCOnfig` looks very weird. Should start with lowercase `class`, are you sure `AppCOnfig` class compiles?

Comment: Also since your `AppConfig` class extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, it should also be annotated with `@EnableWebMvc`

Comment: @pleft AppConfig compiles but when spring tried to get session factory object i creates  error as mention above

Comment: Ok so please edit your question and post the correct `AppConfig` class because `Class AppCOnfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` does not even compile. It should be `class` not `Class`

Comment: Did you check https://frightanic.com/software-development/maven-hbm2ddl-fixing-java-lang-arraystoreexception-sun-reflect-annotation-enumconstantnotpresentexceptionproxy/ ?

Answer (score 0):

An `EnumConstantNotPresentException` is thrown when something tries to reference an enum constant by name when it doesn’t exist. The `Proxy` variant of it is thrown, in my experience, when there’s reflection involved. If you debug your app with a breaking point on the `EnumConstantNotPresentExceptionProxy(Class<? extends Enum<?>>, String)` constructor, you should be able to see the class of the enum and the name of the non-existent constant.